# app crashes in iOS 8 when debugging, but works when not debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8.1

This app work fine on iOS 7 simulator without any issue. But when I'm debugging it on iOS 8.1 simulator it crashes. It would not even reach 1st view controller's viewDidLoad.

Just after compiler leaves applicaitondidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method app crashes.

However I can run already built app in iOS 8.1 simulator without any issue. Crashes only when I'm running the app through Xcode. What could be the reason? (considering the fact that it's already debugging fine in iOS 7) ?

EDIT: (CRASH LOG)

```
UIKit`UIApplicationMain:
0x108ecff1e:  pushq  %rbp
0x108ecff1f:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x108ecff22:  pushq  %r15
0x108ecff24:  pushq  %r14
0x108ecff26:  pushq  %r13
0x108ecff28:  pushq  %r12
0x108ecff2a:  pushq  %rbx
0x108ecff2b:  subq   $0x38, %rsp
0x108ecff2f:  movq   %rcx, -0x48(%rbp)
0x108ecff33:  movq   %rdx, %r15
0x108ecff36:  movq   %rsi, %rbx
0x108ecff39:  movl   %edi, %r13d
0x108ecff3c:  movq   0xb4ca8d(%rip), %rax      ; (void *)0x000000010bcf1070: __stack_chk_guard
0x108ecff43:  movq   (%rax), %rax
0x108ecff46:  movq   %rax, -0x30(%rbp)
0x108ecff4a:  leaq   0xdf66bb(%rip), %r14      ; _UIApplicationLinkedOnVersion
0x108ecff51:  movl   (%r14), %ecx
0x108ecff54:  testl  %ecx, %ecx
0x108ecff56:  jne    0x108ecff7a               ; UIApplicationMain + 92
0x108ecff58:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x108ecff5a:  cmpq   $-0x1, 0xdf05ee(%rip)     ; WebKitSetIsClassic + 7
0x108ecff62:  je     0x108ecffa9               ; UIApplicationMain + 139
0x108ecff64:  leaq   0xdf05e5(%rip), %rdi      ; _UIApplicationLinkedOnVersionOnce
0x108ecff6b:  leaq   0xb4fcfe(%rip), %rsi      ; __block_literal_global1030
0x108ecff72:  callq  0x1096a29e4               ; symbol stub for: dispatch_once
0x108ecff77:  movl   (%r14), %ecx
0x108ecff7a:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x108ecff7c:  cmpl   $0x20100, %ecx
0x108ecff82:  jb     0x108ecffa9               ; UIApplicationMain + 139
0x108ecff84:  movq   0xdb8e15(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010a4d7da8: NSAutoreleasePool
0x108ecff8b:  movq   0xd8d406(%rip), %rsi      ; "alloc"
0x108ecff92:  movq   0xb4d0f7(%rip), %r14      ; (void *)0x000000010a881000: objc_msgSend
0x108ecff99:  callq  *%r14
0x108ecff9c:  movq   0xd8d84d(%rip), %rsi      ; "init"
0x108ecffa3:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ecffa6:  callq  *%r14
0x108ecffa9:  movq   %r15, -0x50(%rbp)
0x108ecffad:  movq   %rax, -0x58(%rbp)
0x108ecffb1:  cmpl   $0x2, %r13d
0x108ecffb5:  jl     0x108ed0019               ; UIApplicationMain + 251
0x108ecffb7:  addq   $0x8, %rbx
0x108ecffbb:  decl   %r13d
0x108ecffbe:  leaq   0x8a9075(%rip), %r14      ; "-BuildDefaultPNG"
0x108ecffc5:  leaq   0x8a907f(%rip), %r15      ; "-RegisterForSystemEvents"
0x108ecffcc:  movq   (%rbx), %r12
0x108ecffcf:  movq   %r12, %rdi
0x108ecffd2:  movq   %r14, %rsi
0x108ecffd5:  callq  0x1096a2cd8               ; symbol stub for: strcmp
0x108ecffda:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x108ecffdc:  je     0x108ed0009               ; UIApplicationMain + 235
0x108ecffde:  movq   %r12, %rdi
0x108ecffe1:  movq   %r15, %rsi
0x108ecffe4:  callq  0x1096a2cd8               ; symbol stub for: strcmp
0x108ecffe9:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x108ecffeb:  je     0x108ed0000               ; UIApplicationMain + 226
0x108ecffed:  movq   %r12, %rdi
0x108ecfff0:  leaq   0x8a906d(%rip), %rsi      ; "--RegisterForSystemEvents"
0x108ecfff7:  callq  0x1096a2cd8               ; symbol stub for: strcmp
0x108ecfffc:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x108ecfffe:  jne    0x108ed0010               ; UIApplicationMain + 242
0x108ed0000:  movb   $0x1, 0xdf656c(%rip)      ; __ShouldLaunchSafe
0x108ed0007:  jmp    0x108ed0010               ; UIApplicationMain + 242
0x108ed0009:  movb   $0x1, 0xdf6561(%rip)      ; __IsRunningTests
0x108ed0010:  addq   $0x8, %rbx
0x108ed0014:  decl   %r13d
0x108ed0017:  jne    0x108ecffcc               ; UIApplicationMain + 174
0x108ed0019:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x108ed001b:  callq  0x1096a1592               ; symbol stub for: BKSDisplayServicesStart
0x108ed0020:  callq  0x108ed0d0b               ; UIApplicationInitialize
0x108ed0025:  movq   0xdb8d24(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x0000000109c9ec80: UIApplication
0x108ed002c:  movq   0xd8d39d(%rip), %rsi      ; "class"
0x108ed0033:  callq  *0xb4d057(%rip)           ; (void *)0x000000010a881000: objc_msgSend
0x108ed0039:  movq   %rax, %r15
0x108ed003c:  movq   -0x50(%rbp), %rbx
0x108ed0040:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
0x108ed0043:  jne    0x108ed0081               ; UIApplicationMain + 355
0x108ed0045:  movq   0xdb8d34(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010a4d7e20: NSBundle
0x108ed004c:  movq   0xd8e0dd(%rip), %rsi      ; "mainBundle"
0x108ed0053:  movq   0xb4d036(%rip), %r14      ; (void *)0x000000010a881000: objc_msgSend
0x108ed005a:  callq  *%r14
0x108ed005d:  movq   0xd8e0d4(%rip), %rsi      ; "infoDictionary"
0x108ed0064:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ed0067:  callq  *%r14
0x108ed006a:  movq   0xd8d38f(%rip), %rsi      ; "objectForKey:"
0x108ed0071:  leaq   0xb8b4b8(%rip), %rdx      ; @"NSPrincipalClass"
0x108ed0078:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ed007b:  callq  *%r14
0x108ed007e:  movq   %rax, %rbx
0x108ed0081:  movq   0xd8e0c0(%rip), %rsi      ; "length"
0x108ed0088:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x108ed008b:  callq  *0xb4cfff(%rip)           ; (void *)0x000000010a881000: objc_msgSend
0x108ed0091:  testq  %rax, %rax
0x108ed0094:  movq   -0x48(%rbp), %r13
0x108ed0098:  je     0x108ed0127               ; UIApplicationMain + 521
0x108ed009e:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x108ed00a1:  callq  0x1096a19ca               ; symbol stub for: NSClassFromString
0x108ed00a6:  movq   %rax, %r15
0x108ed00a9:  testq  %r15, %r15
0x108ed00ac:  jne    0x108ed0127               ; UIApplicationMain + 521
0x108ed00ae:  movq   0xdb8b33(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010a4d8500: NSAssertionHandler
0x108ed00b5:  movq   0xd8d47c(%rip), %rsi      ; "currentHandler"
0x108ed00bc:  movq   0xb4cfcd(%rip), %r12      ; (void *)0x000000010a881000: objc_msgSend
0x108ed00c3:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed00c6:  movq   %rax, -0x50(%rbp)
0x108ed00ca:  movq   0xdb8b1f(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010a4dae90: NSString
0x108ed00d1:  movq   0xd8d468(%rip), %rsi      ; "stringWithUTF8String:"
0x108ed00d8:  leaq   0x8a8fb0(%rip), %rdx      ; "int UIApplicationMain(int, char **, NSString *, NSString *)"
0x108ed00df:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed00e2:  movq   %rax, %r14
0x108ed00e5:  movq   0xdb8b04(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010a4dae90: NSString
0x108ed00ec:  movq   0xd8d44d(%rip), %rsi      ; "stringWithUTF8String:"
0x108ed00f3:  leaq   0x8a868f(%rip), %rdx      ; "/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UIApplication.m"
0x108ed00fa:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed00fd:  movq   %rax, %rcx
0x108ed0100:  movq   0xd8e179(%rip), %rsi      ; "handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:"
0x108ed0107:  movq   %rbx, (%rsp)
0x108ed010b:  leaq   0xb8b43e(%rip), %r9       ; @"Unable to instantiate the UIApplication subclass instance. No class named %@ is loaded."
0x108ed0112:  xorl   %r15d, %r15d
0x108ed0115:  movl   $0xb36, %r8d
0x108ed011b:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x108ed011d:  movq   %r14, %rdx
0x108ed0120:  movq   -0x50(%rbp), %rdi
0x108ed0124:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0127:  leaq   0x330(%rip), %rdi         ; _UIApplicationHandleEvent
0x108ed012e:  callq  0x1096a1d12               ; symbol stub for: GSEventRegisterEventCallBack
0x108ed0133:  leaq   0x8f1(%rip), %rdi         ; _UIApplicationHandleHIDEvent
0x108ed013a:  callq  0x1096a15bc               ; symbol stub for: BKSHIDEventRegisterEventCallback
0x108ed013f:  movq   0xd8d28a(%rip), %rsi      ; "class"
0x108ed0146:  movq   0xb4cf43(%rip), %r12      ; (void *)0x000000010a881000: objc_msgSend
0x108ed014d:  movq   %r15, %rdi
0x108ed0150:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0153:  movq   0xd8e196(%rip), %rsi      ; "registerAsSystemApp"
0x108ed015a:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ed015d:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0160:  movb   %al, 0xdf640d(%rip)       ; __RegisterAsSystemApp
0x108ed0166:  cmpq   $-0x1, 0xdf0372(%rip)     ; __signalRunLoopSource + 7
0x108ed016e:  jne    0x108ed0446               ; UIApplicationMain + 1320
0x108ed0174:  cmpb   $0x0, 0xdf036d(%rip)      ; _UIApplicationIsExtension.once + 7
0x108ed017b:  je     0x108ed0186               ; UIApplicationMain + 616
0x108ed017d:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x108ed017f:  callq  0x1096a1cee               ; symbol stub for: GSEventInitializeAsExtension
0x108ed0184:  jmp    0x108ed0192               ; UIApplicationMain + 628
0x108ed0186:  movzbl 0xdf63e6(%rip), %edi      ; __RegisterAsSystemApp
0x108ed018d:  callq  0x1096a1ce8               ; symbol stub for: GSEventInitialize
0x108ed0192:  movq   0xb4cca7(%rip), %rax      ; (void *)0x000000010ae3f300: NSDefaultRunLoopMode
0x108ed0199:  movq   (%rax), %rdi
0x108ed019c:  callq  0x1096a1d06               ; symbol stub for: GSEventPushRunLoopMode
0x108ed01a1:  movq   0xd8e430(%rip), %rsi      ; "_startWindowServerIfNecessary"
0x108ed01a8:  movq   %r15, %rdi
0x108ed01ab:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed01ae:  movq   0xd8e42b(%rip), %rsi      ; "_startStatusBarServerIfNecessary"
0x108ed01b5:  movq   %r15, %rdi
0x108ed01b8:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed01bb:  movq   %r15, %rdi
0x108ed01be:  callq  0x108ecfdd0               ; UIApplicationInstantiateSingleton
0x108ed01c3:  movq   0xdb8c56(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010e867498: FBSUIApplicationSystemService
0x108ed01ca:  movq   0xd8d1c7(%rip), %rsi      ; "alloc"
0x108ed01d1:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed01d4:  movq   0xd8e40d(%rip), %rsi      ; "initWithQueue:"
0x108ed01db:  movq   0xb4c7fe(%rip), %rdx      ; (void *)0x000000010bbe4780: _dispatch_main_q
0x108ed01e2:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ed01e5:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed01e8:  movq   %rax, 0xdf0319(%rip)      ; __systemAppService
0x108ed01ef:  movq   0xdf6372(%rip), %rdx      ; UIApp
0x108ed01f6:  movq   0xd8d48b(%rip), %rsi      ; "setDelegate:"
0x108ed01fd:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ed0200:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0203:  movq   0xdb8c1e(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010e867650: FBSUIApplicationWorkspace
0x108ed020a:  movq   0xd8d187(%rip), %rsi      ; "alloc"
0x108ed0211:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0214:  movq   %rax, %r14
0x108ed0217:  movq   0xdb8c12(%rip), %rbx      ; (void *)0x000000010e868168: FBSSerialQueue
0x108ed021e:  movq   0xb4cc13(%rip), %rax      ; (void *)0x000000010ae3f308: NSRunLoopCommonModes
0x108ed0225:  movq   (%rax), %rax
0x108ed0228:  movq   %rax, -0x40(%rbp)
0x108ed022c:  leaq   0xb8d9dd(%rip), %rax      ; @"UIInitializationRunLoopMode"
0x108ed0233:  movq   %rax, -0x38(%rbp)
0x108ed0237:  movq   0xdb897a(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010ae78cd8: NSArray
0x108ed023e:  movq   0xd8d0fb(%rip), %rsi      ; "arrayWithObjects:count:"
0x108ed0245:  leaq   -0x40(%rbp), %rdx
0x108ed0249:  movl   $0x2, %ecx
0x108ed024e:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0251:  movq   0xd8e398(%rip), %rsi      ; "queueWithMainRunLoopModes:"
0x108ed0258:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x108ed025b:  movq   %rax, %rdx
0x108ed025e:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0261:  movq   0xd8e390(%rip), %rsi      ; "initWithSerialQueue:"
0x108ed0268:  movq   %r14, %rdi
0x108ed026b:  movq   %rax, %rdx
0x108ed026e:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0271:  movq   %rax, 0xdf0238(%rip)      ; __workspace
0x108ed0278:  movq   0xdf62e9(%rip), %rdx      ; UIApp
0x108ed027f:  movq   0xd8d402(%rip), %rsi      ; "setDelegate:"
0x108ed0286:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ed0289:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed028c:  movq   0xdb8965(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x0000000109ca4540: UIDevice
0x108ed0293:  movq   0xd8d2d6(%rip), %rsi      ; "currentDevice"
0x108ed029a:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed029d:  movq   0xd8d2d4(%rip), %rsi      ; "userInterfaceIdiom"
0x108ed02a4:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ed02a7:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed02aa:  cmpq   $0x1, %rax
0x108ed02ae:  jne    0x108ed02c4               ; UIApplicationMain + 934
0x108ed02b0:  movq   0xdb8af1(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x0000000109cab250: UIClassicController
0x108ed02b7:  movq   0xd8e062(%rip), %rsi      ; "sharedClassicController"
0x108ed02be:  callq  *0xb4cdcc(%rip)           ; (void *)0x000000010a881000: objc_msgSend
0x108ed02c4:  testq  %r13, %r13
0x108ed02c7:  jne    0x108ed0307               ; UIApplicationMain + 1001
0x108ed02c9:  movq   0xdb8ab0(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010a4d7e20: NSBundle
0x108ed02d0:  movq   0xd8de59(%rip), %rsi      ; "mainBundle"
0x108ed02d7:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed02da:  movq   0xd8de57(%rip), %rsi      ; "infoDictionary"
0x108ed02e1:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ed02e4:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed02e7:  movq   0xd8d112(%rip), %rsi      ; "objectForKey:"
0x108ed02ee:  leaq   0xb8b27b(%rip), %rdx      ; @"UIApplicationDelegateClass"
0x108ed02f5:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ed02f8:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed02fb:  movq   %rax, %r13
0x108ed02fe:  testq  %r13, %r13
0x108ed0301:  je     0x108ed0401               ; UIApplicationMain + 1251
0x108ed0307:  movq   %r13, %rdi
0x108ed030a:  callq  0x1096a19ca               ; symbol stub for: NSClassFromString
0x108ed030f:  movq   %rax, %r14
0x108ed0312:  testq  %r14, %r14
0x108ed0315:  jne    0x108ed0384               ; UIApplicationMain + 1126
0x108ed0317:  movq   0xdb88ca(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010a4d8500: NSAssertionHandler
0x108ed031e:  movq   0xd8d213(%rip), %rsi      ; "currentHandler"
0x108ed0325:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0328:  movq   %rax, %r15
0x108ed032b:  movq   0xdb88be(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010a4dae90: NSString
0x108ed0332:  movq   0xd8d207(%rip), %rsi      ; "stringWithUTF8String:"
0x108ed0339:  leaq   0x8a8d4f(%rip), %rdx      ; "int UIApplicationMain(int, char **, NSString *, NSString *)"
0x108ed0340:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0343:  movq   %rax, %rbx
0x108ed0346:  movq   0xdb88a3(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010a4dae90: NSString
0x108ed034d:  movq   0xd8d1ec(%rip), %rsi      ; "stringWithUTF8String:"
0x108ed0354:  leaq   0x8a842e(%rip), %rdx      ; "/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UIApplication.m"
0x108ed035b:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed035e:  movq   %rax, %rcx
0x108ed0361:  movq   0xd8df18(%rip), %rsi      ; "handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:"
0x108ed0368:  movq   %r13, (%rsp)
0x108ed036c:  leaq   0xb8b21d(%rip), %r9       ; @"Unable to instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance. No class named %@ is loaded."
0x108ed0373:  movl   $0xb62, %r8d
0x108ed0379:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x108ed037b:  movq   %rbx, %rdx
0x108ed037e:  movq   %r15, %rdi
0x108ed0381:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0384:  movq   0xdb89c5(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x0000000109c9ec80: UIApplication
0x108ed038b:  movq   0xd8d03e(%rip), %rsi      ; "class"
0x108ed0392:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0395:  movq   0xd8e264(%rip), %rsi      ; "isSubclassOfClass:"
0x108ed039c:  movq   %r14, %rdi
0x108ed039f:  movq   %rax, %rdx
0x108ed03a2:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed03a5:  movq   0xdf61bc(%rip), %rbx      ; UIApp
0x108ed03ac:  testb  %al, %al
0x108ed03ae:  je     0x108ed03c5               ; UIApplicationMain + 1191
0x108ed03b0:  movq   0xd8d2d1(%rip), %rsi      ; "setDelegate:"
0x108ed03b7:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x108ed03ba:  movq   %rbx, %rdx
0x108ed03bd:  callq  *0xb4cccd(%rip)           ; (void *)0x000000010a881000: objc_msgSend
0x108ed03c3:  jmp    0x108ed0401               ; UIApplicationMain + 1251
0x108ed03c5:  movq   0xd8cfcc(%rip), %rsi      ; "alloc"
0x108ed03cc:  movq   %r14, %rdi
0x108ed03cf:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed03d2:  movq   0xd8d417(%rip), %rsi      ; "init"
0x108ed03d9:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ed03dc:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed03df:  movq   0xd8d4d2(%rip), %rsi      ; "autorelease"
0x108ed03e6:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108ed03e9:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed03ec:  movq   0xd8e215(%rip), %rsi      ; "_setDelegate:assumeOwnership:"
0x108ed03f3:  movl   $0x1, %ecx
0x108ed03f8:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x108ed03fb:  movq   %rax, %rdx
0x108ed03fe:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0401:  movq   0xd8cf78(%rip), %rsi      ; "release"
0x108ed0408:  movq   -0x58(%rbp), %rdi
0x108ed040c:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed040f:  movq   0xdf6152(%rip), %rdi      ; UIApp
0x108ed0416:  movq   0xd8e1f3(%rip), %rsi      ; "_run"
0x108ed041d:  callq  *%r12
0x108ed0420:  movq   0xb4c5a9(%rip), %rax      ; (void *)0x000000010bcf1070: __stack_chk_guard
0x108ed0427:  movq   (%rax), %rax
0x108ed042a:  cmpq   -0x30(%rbp), %rax
0x108ed042e:  jne    0x108ed0441               ; UIApplicationMain + 1315
0x108ed0430:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x108ed0432:  addq   $0x38, %rsp
0x108ed0436:  popq   %rbx
0x108ed0437:  popq   %r12
0x108ed0439:  popq   %r13
0x108ed043b:  popq   %r14
0x108ed043d:  popq   %r15
0x108ed043f:  popq   %rbp
0x108ed0440:  retq   
0x108ed0441:  callq  0x1096a2936               ; symbol stub for: __stack_chk_fail
0x108ed0446:  leaq   0xdf0093(%rip), %rdi      ; _UIApplicationIsExtension.once
0x108ed044d:  leaq   0xb4f57c(%rip), %rsi      ; __block_literal_global616
0x108ed0454:  callq  0x1096a29e4               ; symbol stub for: dispatch_once
0x108ed0459:  jmp    0x108ed0174               ; UIApplicationMain + 598
```

breakpoint stops near :

```
0x108ed0420:  movq   0xb4c5a9(%rip), %rax      ; (void *)0x000000010bcf1070: __stack_chk_guard
```

Comment: Do you get a crashlog or something? 
Try enabling zombies and set an "All Exceptions" Breakpoint

Comment: @HermannKlecker I've enabled All Exceptions, but still end up in UIApplicationMain's main method when crashed. However I can see these string in debugging area :
 argc:(int) argc = 1
 argv:(char **) argv = 0x00007fff5740d4e8

Comment: Look at this `Unable to instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance. No class named %@ is loaded` apparently it can't initialise the AppDelegate. Can you please show your `main` method in the `main.m` file?

Comment: it's same `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
`

Comment: however whenever app crashes, I see this : http://oi61.tinypic.com/syo579.jpg in debugging area.

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx Is the name of your app delegate class `AppDelegate` ?

Comment: @spagosx yes it's `AppDelegate`

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx Last try, check if AppDelegate file is linked to your target so it's present in the Compile Sources section of Build Phases for that target.

Comment: When you get to the breakpoint then press "continue" once or twice more. Some sort of error message should appear. Plus a crashlog should appear. If not then try removing the AllExceptions breakpoint again.

Comment: @HermannKlecker thanks for the info. I kept pressing continue then app suddenly launched. Then I removed all exceptions and then app started running without crashing. Thank you! If you will post this comment as an answer I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: Good news. No, I will not post this as an answer because it is no answer. You must have done something else that make the difference. Once you find out what it was then you should answer your question yourself. Somebody else may run into the same probelm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with xcode 6.3 and swift 1.2. It seems that there is a problem with the pod that you've imported. Try to update the pod installed, then restart xcode and try again. It worked for me :)